# Multicolumn Explode

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am trying to turn multiple columns into a single column, without the "null" ones and keep the identifier of each row

| Identifier | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog | Cow | Sheep | Dinosaur |
| 2 | Dog | Pig |  |  |
| 3 | Bull | Cow | Elephant |  |

I want the new 2 columns like this, the original dataframe might have lots of columns, 20, 30, maybe more.

| Identifier | Var |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog |
| 1 | Cow |
| 1 | Sheep |
| 1 | Dinosaur |
| 2 | Dog |
| 2 | Pig |
| 3 | Bull |
| 3 | Cow |
| 3 | Elephant |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try looking into pandas pivot methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `melt()` for this

```
df.melt(id_vars = 'Identifier')[['Identifier', 'value']].dropna().sort_values('Identifier')
```